# What is the error "field `id` of struct `Todo` is private"?

Tags: rust

I want to put a value in the structure, but I get an error because it is private. How do I resolve it?
I have it set to pub, but I get this error.

```rust
use actix_web::{get, post, web, HttpResponse,Responder};
use crate::app::model::todo::Todo;
#[get("/todos/{id}")]
async fn get_todo(id: web::Path<u32>) -> impl Responder {
    let id_option: Option<u32> = Some(id.into_inner());
    HttpResponse::Ok().json(Todo {
        id: id_option,
        content: String::from("やること"),
        completed: false,
    })
}

#[post("/todos")]
async fn post_todo(todo: web::Json<Todo>) -> impl Responder {
    println!("post_todo");
    println!("{:?}", todo);
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("ok")
}
```

```
pub struct Todo {
    id: Option<u32>,
    content: String,
    completed: bool,
}
```

Comment: I have it set to pub, but I get this error.

Comment: Read the linked thread again. You have set the struct to `pub`, but not its fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your `struct` and were is being used are not part of the same module, so declaring the struct pub won't be enough, you have to grant visibility to the fields.

This program would compile fine:

```
struct Todo {
    id: Option<u32>,
    content: String,
    completed: bool,
}

fn main() {
    let t = Todo {
        id: Some(1),
        content: String::from("やること"),
        completed: false,
    };
    println!("{}", t.content);
}
```

but this wouldn't:

```
mod todo {
    struct Todo {
        id: Option<u32>,
        content: String,
        completed: bool,
    }
}    

fn main() {
    let t = todo::Todo {
        id: Some(1),
        content: String::from("やること"),
        completed: false,
    };
    println!("{}", t.content);
}
```

if you add pub to the struct but not to the fields, the struct is now visible from your main, but not its contents. If you add pub to the fields, you can create the struct from main, as well as access its fields:

```
mod todo {
    pub struct Todo {
        pub id: Option<u32>,
        pub content: String,
        pub completed: bool,
    }
}    

fn main() {
    let t = todo::Todo {
        id: Some(1),
        content: String::from("やること"),
        completed: false,
    };
    println!("{}", t.content);
}
```

If you make only the struct pub, but not the fields, this would allow you to see and use the structure from main, while protecting its fields from direct access:

```
mod todo {
    pub struct Todo {
        id: Option<u32>,
        content: String,
        completed: bool,
    }
    
    impl Todo {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            Todo {
                id: Some(1),
                content: String::from("やること"),
                completed: false,
            }
        }
        
        pub fn content(&self) -> String {
            self.content.to_owned()
        }
    }
}    

fn main() {
    let t = todo::Todo::new();
    println!("{}", t.content());
}
```

If you tried to create a struct directly from main as in `Todo {.....}` instead of using `new()`, you would get an error. if you tried to print `t.content` instead of using the `content()` function, you would get an error.